# Wise Installation Studio: What is WiseCustomCall

Tags: windows-installer, wise

I am upgrading an old Wise for Windows installation to a newer version of Wise Installation Studio, and the WiseCustomCall resource is now marked as <unspecified>.  The .wsi compiles into a .msi without issue, but then fails during runtime, not being able to locate "location: WiseCustomCall, command: g0".

Can anyone provide some information about WiseCustomCall?  What specifically does it do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe WiseCustomCall is the Wise Installation's handler for handling Custom Action In-Script Executions.

Can you confirm that you recieve error 172*? (what error are you recieving?)

To troubleshoot this error message:

Check the location of the custom action to ensure the file is available at the time of execution. A good location to place a custom action that can be run following the rest of the installation completing, is after InstallFinalize in the Execute Immediate sequence in MSI script. 
Create a log file by executing the .MSI using the following command line in the Start > Run prompt:

```
msiexec /i  <full path of MSI package> /l*v <path to log file>.
```

Occasionally, the WiseCustomCall action has disassociated itself to the custom action. Go to the Resources page in Installation Expert, locate the WiseCustomCall entry, and browse to the WiseDll.DLL.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce anymore - the disassociation is the likely culprit though from your explanation.